# Is there an accepted way for using ellipsis "…" in quoted text?

Tags: пунктуація

Say, we have a quote:

> *Ну що б, здавалося, слова…
>
>     Слова та голос — більш нічого.
>
>     А серце б’ється — ожива,
>
>     Як їх почує!.. Знать, од Бога
>
>     І голос той, і ті слова
>
>     Ідуть меж люди!…*
>     — Т. Шевченко

[The punctuation rules say](http://pravila-uk-mova.com.ua/index/punktuacija/0-26) that if I need to skip a part of the quote, I have to use ellipsis: `…`
However, the quoted text has its own ellipsis, so mine would unnecessarily collide with the author's.

**What is the accepted way to quote in this case?** The result would be:

> *Ну що б, здавалося, слова…
>
>     Слова та голос — більш нічого.
>
>     **???**
>
>     Знать, од Бога
>
>     І голос той, і ті слова
>
>     **???***
>     — Т. Шевченко

At the moment, I use it like this `[…]`, but I'm not sure if it is grammatical.

Comment: I believe that using `[...]` is the accepted convention in English, though I'm unsure about Ukrainian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good question!

Although I've failed to find the explicit answer to the question in any authoritative sources, there are a couple of minor source which offer **<...>** (ellipsis in angle brackets) option for:

> - скорочуючи цитату, на місці пропуску ставлять три крапки в кутових дужках: <...>

Methodological recommendations to undergraduate's thesis on foreign literature of Kherson State University (*[link](http://www.kspu.edu/FileDownload.ashx?id=780fdb74-55e6-4c02-a816-32d33a74e267) to that is for downloading .doc file*)

> - Три крапки в кутових (ламаних) дужках <...> у цитованому тексті означають пропуск кількох речень, абзацу чи більше.

[Textbook](http://p-for.com/book_293_glava_60_%C2%A7_57._Rozd%D1%96lov%D1%96_znaki_pri_%EF%BF%BD.html)  of Kirovograd State Pedagogical University - (Ковтюх С. Л. К 56 Репетитор (як навчитися грамотно писати): Навчальний посібник з практичного курсу української мови. — 2-е вид., випр. й допов. — К.: «ВД «Професіонал», 2007. — 592 с.)